# WordPress ABSPATH PHP File Issues

Tags: php, wordpress

Good afternoon,

I am using WordPress for my site and have some custom php files in my child theme. These are used for processing form data, sending emails, sending SMS messages and also creating password encoded zip files.

I wanted to not allow direct access to these php files, so I read including the following would stop this issue:

```
 if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}
```

I have checked my wp-config file to ensure ABSPATH is defined.

I am assuming that because my form action path is a direct path to the php file URL i.e `action="mywordpresswebsite.com/folder/myFormFile.php"` that perhaps this is outside of WordPress' initialisation process and therefore ABSPATH isn't being defined?

I'm not entirely sure and am also wondering about people's thoughts on if there are security issues with the way I have done this.

Is there security issues if my php files' are directly accessible? Just to confirm, the actual process form script denies access to all GET requests, it's the other php files that are required that would contain the ABSPATH check.

Any help is massively appreciated, and I want to ensure my site is secure to the highest degree.

Kind regards

Comment: There seems to be a fundamental contradition in your question, you say you use the existence of the constant to disable direct access to files (a common way to do it), but on the other hand you say you use a "direct path to the php file URL" which is, actually, a direct acces to the file.. this means you are using a way to disallow what you want to do.. What you want is actually more an authentification system, to ensure your scripts can only be called from your form, but can be accessed directly. There may be a way to do it using Wordpress functions instead

Comment: Of course a WordPress constant is not available, when you execute a stand-alone script, that doesn't have anything(?) to do with WP. Targeting such stand-alone files _directly_ from the frontend, is absolutely against the principles of WordPress. If you want to do it _properly_, then you use WP functionality, instead of trying to navigate your way around it.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. So would you suggest instead changing the action path to something like this : action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-post.php'); ?>" adding actions for the logged in, and non logged in user, then having a function that requires my form processing php files. Would this create the ABSPATH variable?

Comment: Yes this means you should post to "admin-post.php". But it means you will not need the `ABSPATH` check, which is only used for codes that are only meant to be included in wordpress files (via PHP's `include` or `require`) where the constant is already defined. You won't need an extra file at all, all the form data processing code will be either in "functions.php" or in a custom plugin (called from somewhere in "functions.php" probably)

Comment: Thank you for your helpful reply. I really appreciate it. By "then having a function that requires my form processing php files", I meant that if my WordPress function in functions.php would require the script at mywordpresswebsite.com/folder/myFormFile.php . This way I could still keep my file structure and not allow direct file access if I were to add the ABSPATH checks. I hope I am explaining what I mean well haha. Is this an acceptable way to do it or would you still suggest doing it via custom plugins.  There are quite a lot of files so I'm trying to keep it clean.

Comment: Just to clarify, "mywordpresswebsite.com/folder/myFormFile.php" would not be a call to the url, I would change it to the correct server system file path

Comment: A common pattern is to encapsulate your code using classes and/or functions, and having that code live in dedicated files. If accessed directly, PHP will parse the files for syntax issues and symbol discovery, but nothing else will happen since nothing is executing the code. You then use WordPress actions to invoke your code, which guarantees that you are operating in a WordPress context.

Comment: I would suggest consider handling form submissions and other actions through WordPress's admin-ajax.php or REST API, ensuring all requests pass through WordPress's security and permission checks.